# statement.execute() returns error with Slash at the end of PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

When executing pl/sql im obtaining an error :

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 316: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.
```

PLSQL example:

```
DECLARE
   SQL1   VARCHAR2 (1500);
   SQL2   VARCHAR2 (1500);
BEGIN
   SQL1   := 'INSERT INTO das_html_caption VALUES (''test_test'')';
   SQL2   := 'DELETE FROM das_html_caption where wording = ''test_test''';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL2;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL1;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL2;

   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Java:

```
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = null;
boolean ret = statement.execute( sql.getValue() );
```

is it correct error ? or i'm doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The slash is how you execute the anonymous block through an interactive environment such as SQL*Plus.  If you are executing this block by a call from Java you don't need the terminating slash.

Answer (score 2):

Found answer. Had to made more complcated request to google :)

> As the message indicates, the compiler
>   doesn't want to encounter the symbol
>   "/", so just remove it. That simple.
>   Let me explain. When using sqlplus or
>   an SQL worksheet in sqldev, you do
>   well appending your PL/SQL blocks with
>   the slash. However, when using the
>   procedure editor (native to sqldev),
>   you'll have to remove it. Don't know
>   why they made this set of rules, but
>   until they relax them, we'll have to
>   obey them ;-)

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=519670