# TRIGGER AUTO_NUM_GEN compiled Warning: execution completed with warning

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I run the following statements in oracle sql developer using oracle 11g express as my database. I only run into problems when i try to create the trigger. I get the message -

```
TRIGGER AUTO_NUM_GEN compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning
```

The SQL-

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (mynums NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE SEQUENCE myschema.seq_of_nums MINVALUE 1 
START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 10; 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myschema.auto_num_gen 
BEFORE INSERT ON myschema.mytable FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN SELECT seq_of_nums.nextval INTO :new.mynums FROM DUAL; end; /
```

What is my mistake and why won't it work ?

I ran the diagnostic query -

```
show errors trigger myschema.auto_num_gen;
```

And saw -

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored
```

On the side,
When the same code is run through java i also get the error -

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04098: trigger 
'MYTABLE.MYSCHEMA.AUTO_NUM_GEN ' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Comment: similar post - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289723/statement-execute-returns-error-with-slash-at-the-end-of-pl-sql

Answer (score 0):

The slash / at the end is your enemy ! Remove it and the code works !